# Python socket Queue error in windows

Tags: python, select, queue

I copy/pasted two simple Python scripts (source: https://pymotw.com/2/select/ edited both a little). 
The scripts run perfect on my linux computer, but give an error on my windows computer. How is that possible?

Error on my windows computer:

```
  File "C:\test\server.py", line 76, in startserver
    next_msg = message_queues[s].get_nowait()
KeyError: <socket._socketobject object at 0x035D67D8>
```

After the error-message the server script stops running.

server.py:

```
import socket
import select
import Queue

def startserver():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setblocking(0)

    server_address = ('localhost', 12346)
    print 'Start server op %s poort %s' % (server_address)
    server.bind(server_address)

    server.listen(5)

    # Sockets from which we expect to read
    inputs = [ server ]

    # Sockets to which we expect to write
    outputs = [ ]

    # Outgoing message queues (socket:Queue)
    message_queues = {}

    while inputs:
        # Wait for at least one of the sockets to be ready for processing
        print '\nwaiting for the next event.'
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)

        # A. Handle inputs 
        for s in readable:

            if s is server:
                # A "readable" server socket is ready to accept a connection
                connection, client_address = s.accept()
                print 'new connection from', client_address
                connection.setblocking(0)
                inputs.append(connection)

                # Give the connection a queue for data we want to send
                message_queues[connection] = Queue.Queue()

            else:
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    # A readable client socket has data
                    print 'received "%s" from %s.' % (data, s.getpeername())
                    message_queues[s].put(data)
                    # Add output channel for response
                    if s not in outputs:
                        outputs.append(s)

                else:              
                    #Interpret empty result as closed connection
                    print 'closing', client_address, 'after reading no data.'
                    # Stop listening for input on the connection
                    if s in outputs:
                        outputs.remove(s)
                    inputs.remove(s)
                    s.close()

                    # Remove message queue
                    del message_queues[s]

        #Handle outputs. 
        for s in writable:
            try:
                next_msg = message_queues[s].get_nowait()
            except Queue.Empty:
               # No messages waiting so stop checking for writability.
                print 'output queue for', s.getpeername(), 'is empty'
                outputs.remove(s)
            else:
                print 'sending "%s" to %s' % (next_msg, s.getpeername())
                s.send(next_msg)

        #Handle "exceptional conditions" 
        for s in exceptional:
            print 'handling exceptional condition for', s.getpeername()
            # Stop listening for input on the connection
            inputs.remove(s)
            if s in outputs:
                outputs.remove(s)
                s.close()
            # Remove message queue
            del message_queues[s]

startserver()
```

client.py:

```
import socket
import sys

messages = [ 'This is the message. ',
             'It will be sent ',
             'in parts.',
             ]
server_address = ('localhost', 12346)

# Create a TCP/IP socket
socks = [ socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM),
          socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM),
          ]

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
print 'connecting to %s port %s' % (server_address)
for s in socks:
    s.connect(server_address)


for message in messages:

    # Send messages on both sockets
    for s in socks:
        print '%s: sending "%s"' % (s.getsockname(), message)
        s.send(message)

    # Read responses on both sockets
    for s in socks:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print '%s: received "%s"' % (s.getsockname(), data)
        if not data:
            print 'closing socket', s.getsockname()
            s.close()
```

Comment: Note Using Python’s file objects with select() works for Unix, but is not supported under Windows.

Comment: Hmm, I see. So I have to find another way to make it work. Thanks for the info!

Comment: if you find it, please answer the question so we can close it as solved